# Не понимаю почему не происходит изменение содержимого объекта класса

Tags: java, классы

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сложить 2 числа которые представлены в виде reversed linked list. [текст задачи](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) Пытаюсь понять чужое решение на Java и мне не ясно почему в строке `ListNode new_node = new ListNode(last_digit);` на каждой итерации не происходит изменение содержимого объекта new_node а создается новый node с тем же названием? Как это работает? Спасибо за помощь. Весь код ниже.

```
public class ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode next;
     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 }

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummy_head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode l3 = dummy_head;

        int carry = 0;
        while (l1 != null || l2 != null) {
            int l1_val = (l1 != null) ? l1.val : 0;
            int l2_val = (l2 != null) ? l2.val : 0;

            int current_sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
            carry = current_sum / 10;
            int last_digit = current_sum % 10;

            ListNode new_node = new ListNode(last_digit);
            l3.next = new_node;

            if (l1 != null) l1 = l1.next;
            if (l2 != null) l2 = l2.next;
            l3 = l3.next;
        }

        if (carry > 0) {
            ListNode new_node = new ListNode(carry);
            l3.next = new_node;
            l3 = l3.next;
        }

        return dummy_head.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас вроде как цикл отдельно и if отдельно

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за того, что создание объекта `ListNode new_node = new ListNode(last_digit)` находится внутри цикла `while`, как и l1_val, l2_val, current_sum, last_digit, то при каждой его итерации, программа будет "забывать" значения объектов, инициализированных в его теле, и инициализировать их заново.

На самом деле, объекты не "забываются". Каждый раз, когда создается новый объект, и по ссылке "привязывается" на место старого, старый просто ждет пока сборщик мусора поймет, что этот объект больше не будет использоваться и удалит его из памяти.
То же самое произойдет с объектами, инициализированными в теле метода, после того как он вернет результат.

UPD: [Хорошая серия статей про сборщик мусора и работу с памятью в Java](https://habr.com/ru/post/269621/)

Comment: что такое сборщик мусора? насколько "безопасно такое решение" на больших объемах данных (ведь если я не контролирую остались ли в памяти эти данные, то в какой-то момент их там может не быть и цепочка сломается?)

Comment: @sleet Добавил ссылочку на статью в хабре, в которой есть ответы на твои вопросы. На самом деле это очень важная тема и ей стоит уделить много внимания. На всех собеседованиях спрашивают про это.

Comment: @sleet, если я смог ответить на твой вопрос, то пометь мой ответ ответом на твой вопрос, чтобы твой вопрос не попадал в фильтр неотвеченные.